# Evaluate function within ffmpeg drawtext

Tags: ffmpeg, command-line-arguments

I am looking to display a counter that is a multiple of the frame number on a video created with ffmpeg. Previous answers on SO taught me that a command of the form

```
ffmpeg -y -r 25  -pattern_type glob -i '*.jpg' -vf "text='%{n}': start_number=0: x=0: y=0: fontcolor=black: fontsize=30: box=1: boxcolor=white: boxborderw=5" -c:a copy movie.mp4
```

Will display the frame number, and this works nicely. But if I try to evaluate an expression within the `%{}`, e.g.

```
ffmpeg -y -r 25  -pattern_type glob -i '*.jpg' -vf "text='%{n*50}': start_number=0: x=0: y=0: fontcolor=black: fontsize=30: box=1: boxcolor=white: boxborderw=5" -c:a copy movie.mp4
```

Then I get the following error

```
[Parsed_drawtext_0 @ 0x55683f9b00] %{n*50} is not known
```

on each frame. What is the proper syntax to evaluate `n*50` and display in `drawtext`? TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's missing the `e` function specifier. Try

```
ffmpeg -y -r 25  -pattern_type glob -i '*.jpg' \
-vf "drawtext=text='%{e\:n*50}': start_number=0: x=0: y=0: fontcolor=black: fontsize=30: box=1: boxcolor=white: boxborderw=5" \
-c:a copy movie.mp4
```

Comment: Thank you!  I tried `e:` but not `e:\`.

Comment: Invalid syntax. Where's the filter name?

Comment: You might want to throw the `scale` filter in there, as well as adding the `drawtext` filter name.

Comment: @gyan - good catch. I overlooked it as I just copied & pasted OP's command